# Resize background image of div to always fit div on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know how I make it so that my background in the 'header' div always has the right size no matter on what screen you're on. It schould take 90% of the window. I think you'll see what I mean if you look at my code.

My background image is 3840x2400. If you were to use an image of that size I think you'd understand where my problem lies ?

**EDIT:**

@MarcHjorth solution worked for me on the desktop, but thi image is to big and cropped now when looking at it on the phone..

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: grey;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}
ul#horizontal-list {
  list-style: none;
}
ul#horizontal-list li {
  display: inline;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  float: center;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-image: url("img/bg/background1.png");
 background-color: grey;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}
.body {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.content {
 margin: auto;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: white;
 color: black;
 border-right: double;
 border-left: double;
 text-align: justify;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: arial;
 padding: 10% 5%;
}
.footer {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#copyright {
 display: table;
}
#cpy {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  <meta name="description" content="My Personal Portfolio">
  <title>John's Work</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="body">
  <div class="content">      
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ac ipsum non diam faucibus dignissim. Praesent a dolor tincidunt, rutrum diam ut, convallis orci. Maecenas eleifend, sapien id blandit rutrum, enim augue cursus magna, vitae varius orci nulla eu arcu. Cras ultrices condimentum libero nec vulputate. Praesent id ante dignissim, congue elit id, iaculis eros. Aliquam lacus quam, facilisis et pulvinar quis, hendrerit varius erat. Duis feugiat imperdiet lobortis. Ut et faucibus dui. Integer quis bibendum tortor, at mattis dolor. Sed id lacus nec nisi iaculis blandit. Duis nec ligula orci. Quisque tincidunt, orci id tincidunt consequat, eros erat dictum urna, vel ultricies sem nisl eu nunc. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse at malesuada magna, in suscipit purus.

Fusce facilisis pharetra dui, ut cursus orci maximus non. Cras nec magna ac odio ornare ornare. Proin id commodo eros. Phasellus dui est, malesuada non mi sit amet, fringilla rhoncus ante. Phasellus non elit id est cursus malesuada. Maecenas accumsan erat in urna pulvinar, sit amet egestas felis facilisis. Nullam tincidunt porta nulla, a consectetur sapien venenatis in. Phasellus elementum est sit amet sem accumsan tincidunt. In semper vulputate risus, sed sollicitudin libero consectetur eget. Curabitur pulvinar eleifend augue. Sed facilisis ligula sed arcu vulputate tempus.

Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Ut mi nisi, mattis sed est a, luctus aliquet metus. Integer fringilla, massa nec laoreet dapibus, odio sem convallis massa, a vestibulum tellus mi in massa. Sed at vulputate velit, id sagittis sem. Vestibulum ac libero massa. Vivamus et libero vel orci auctor sodales a a quam. Vivamus semper tortor eget lacus euismod, non dignissim tellus feugiat. Donec tincidunt nisi at ornare ullamcorper. Nulla at mi nulla. Phasellus ligula ante, vehicula sit amet mauris et, consectetur mollis odio.

Donec massa risus, ultricies et enim quis, vestibulum consectetur arcu. Nunc sed convallis dui, sagittis imperdiet metus. Sed non ultrices velit. Nullam arcu sem, varius non pulvinar id, convallis eget erat. Nam porta tincidunt lorem, non venenatis sapien hendrerit vitae. Suspendisse nec est leo. Nunc commodo, lectus nec facilisis laoreet, ex velit dapibus dui, et aliquet lacus est non velit. Vestibulum nisl velit, tempor vel lacus at, ultricies pellentesque nisi. Mauris velit tortor, aliquam a magna eget, efficitur fringilla erat. Praesent massa nisl, maximus sit amet viverra in, varius vel urna.

Pellentesque eget leo vitae neque dictum egestas at ullamcorper nulla. Aenean lacinia venenatis metus, in faucibus dolor sollicitudin eget. Sed volutpat sit amet urna vel molestie. Donec dignissim velit tortor, a blandit ligula commodo dapibus. Vestibulum ac dolor facilisis mauris maximus mattis. Nullam vitae libero ut ligula sodales accumsan et vel dui. Quisque dapibus, lacus accumsan interdum efficitur, tellus augue maximus ipsum, quis ultricies dolor justo in diam. Pellentesque id lobortis diam. Suspendisse mollis eget orci eu auctor. Nullam porttitor arcu mi, nec varius magna viverra quis. Fusce eleifend sodales turpis et hendrerit.
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="footer" id="copyright" style="text-align:center">
    <div id="cpy">&copy; DA COSTA JOAO (2019)</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know if this is allowed on here but maybe have a look at the page itself ?

https://the-work-of-john.000webhostapp.com

If you were to open the page on your phone you would notice that under the background image there will be a gray space, how do I get rid o it ?..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I added a dummy image to your code, so we can see what you are talking about

Comment: Use `background-size: cover` instead of `contain` ?

Comment: @MarcHjorth Oh Wow, such a simple answer to this problem! Thanks alot mate!! It fixed the issue on the desktop sized screens but if you were to look at it on your phone, the background image is now to big and cropped..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `background-size: 100% 100%;` instead of `background-size: contain;` like that your image will fit width `<div>`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: grey;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}

ul#horizontal-list {
  list-style: none;
}

ul#horizontal-list li {
  display: inline;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  float: center;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-image: url("https://dummyimage.com/3840x2400/ccc/333");
 background-color: grey;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.body {
  /*height: 100%;*/
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  overflow: hidden;

}

.content {
 margin: auto;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: white;
 color: black;
 border-right: double;
 border-left: double;
 text-align: justify;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: arial;
 padding-top: 10%;
 padding-bottom: 10%;
 padding-left: 5%;
 padding-right: 5%;
}

.footer {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#copyright {
 display: table;
}

#cpy{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  <meta name="description" content="My Personal Portfolio">
  <title>John's Work</title>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="navbar">

    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>


  <div class="header">

  </div>

  <div class="body">
  <div class="content">
  
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ac ipsum non diam faucibus dignissim. Praesent a dolor tincidunt, rutrum diam ut, convallis orci. Maecenas eleifend, sapien id blandit rutrum, enim augue cursus magna, vitae varius orci nulla eu arcu. Cras ultrices condimentum libero nec vulputate. Praesent id ante dignissim, congue elit id, iaculis eros. Aliquam lacus quam, facilisis et pulvinar quis, hendrerit varius erat. Duis feugiat imperdiet lobortis. Ut et faucibus dui. Integer quis bibendum tortor, at mattis dolor. Sed id lacus nec nisi iaculis blandit. Duis nec ligula orci. Quisque tincidunt, orci id tincidunt consequat, eros erat dictum urna, vel ultricies sem nisl eu nunc. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse at malesuada magna, in suscipit purus.

Fusce facilisis pharetra dui, ut cursus orci maximus non. Cras nec magna ac odio ornare ornare. Proin id commodo eros. Phasellus dui est, malesuada non mi sit amet, fringilla rhoncus ante. Phasellus non elit id est cursus malesuada. Maecenas accumsan erat in urna pulvinar, sit amet egestas felis facilisis. Nullam tincidunt porta nulla, a consectetur sapien venenatis in. Phasellus elementum est sit amet sem accumsan tincidunt. In semper vulputate risus, sed sollicitudin libero consectetur eget. Curabitur pulvinar eleifend augue. Sed facilisis ligula sed arcu vulputate tempus.

Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Ut mi nisi, mattis sed est a, luctus aliquet metus. Integer fringilla, massa nec laoreet dapibus, odio sem convallis massa, a vestibulum tellus mi in massa. Sed at vulputate velit, id sagittis sem. Vestibulum ac libero massa. Vivamus et libero vel orci auctor sodales a a quam. Vivamus semper tortor eget lacus euismod, non dignissim tellus feugiat. Donec tincidunt nisi at ornare ullamcorper. Nulla at mi nulla. Phasellus ligula ante, vehicula sit amet mauris et, consectetur mollis odio.

Donec massa risus, ultricies et enim quis, vestibulum consectetur arcu. Nunc sed convallis dui, sagittis imperdiet metus. Sed non ultrices velit. Nullam arcu sem, varius non pulvinar id, convallis eget erat. Nam porta tincidunt lorem, non venenatis sapien hendrerit vitae. Suspendisse nec est leo. Nunc commodo, lectus nec facilisis laoreet, ex velit dapibus dui, et aliquet lacus est non velit. Vestibulum nisl velit, tempor vel lacus at, ultricies pellentesque nisi. Mauris velit tortor, aliquam a magna eget, efficitur fringilla erat. Praesent massa nisl, maximus sit amet viverra in, varius vel urna.

Pellentesque eget leo vitae neque dictum egestas at ullamcorper nulla. Aenean lacinia venenatis metus, in faucibus dolor sollicitudin eget. Sed volutpat sit amet urna vel molestie. Donec dignissim velit tortor, a blandit ligula commodo dapibus. Vestibulum ac dolor facilisis mauris maximus mattis. Nullam vitae libero ut ligula sodales accumsan et vel dui. Quisque dapibus, lacus accumsan interdum efficitur, tellus augue maximus ipsum, quis ultricies dolor justo in diam. Pellentesque id lobortis diam. Suspendisse mollis eget orci eu auctor. Nullam porttitor arcu mi, nec varius magna viverra quis. Fusce eleifend sodales turpis et hendrerit.
  </div>
</div>

  <div class="footer" id="copyright" style="text-align:center">
    <div id="cpy">&copy; DA COSTA JOAO (2019)</div>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks! Care to explain what using 100% twice does ?

Comment: You are welcome, first value: width of the image, second value: height

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: grey;
  /*background-attachment: fixed;*/
  /*background-size: 100% auto;*/
}

ul#horizontal-list {
  list-style: none;
}

ul#horizontal-list li {
  display: inline;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  float: center;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
  position: relative;
}

.header:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://dummyimage.com/3840x2400/ccc/333");
  background-color: grey;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 1960px) {
  .header:before {
    background-image: url("https://dummyimage.com/1960x1225/ccc/333");
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .header:before {
    background-image: url("https://dummyimage.com/1024x640/ccc/333");
  }
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .header:before {
    background-image: url("https://dummyimage.com/800x500/ccc/333");
  }
}

.body {
  /*height: 100%;*/
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border-right: double;
  border-left: double;
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: arial;
  padding-top: 5%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
}

.footer {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#copyright {
  display: table;
}

#cpy {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">

  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>


<div class="header">

</div>

<div class="body">
  <div class="content">

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ac ipsum non diam faucibus dignissim. Praesent a dolor tincidunt, rutrum diam ut, convallis orci. Maecenas eleifend, sapien id blandit rutrum, enim augue cursus magna, vitae varius orci nulla
    eu arcu. Cras ultrices condimentum libero nec vulputate. Praesent id ante dignissim, congue elit id, iaculis eros. Aliquam lacus quam, facilisis et pulvinar quis, hendrerit varius erat. Duis feugiat imperdiet lobortis. Ut et faucibus dui. Integer
    quis bibendum tortor, at mattis dolor. Sed id lacus nec nisi iaculis blandit. Duis nec ligula orci. Quisque tincidunt, orci id tincidunt consequat, eros erat dictum urna, vel ultricies sem nisl eu nunc. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse at malesuada magna,
    in suscipit purus. Fusce facilisis pharetra dui, ut cursus orci maximus non. Cras nec magna ac odio ornare ornare. Proin id commodo eros. Phasellus dui est, malesuada non mi sit amet, fringilla rhoncus ante. Phasellus non elit id est cursus malesuada.
    Maecenas accumsan erat in urna pulvinar, sit amet egestas felis facilisis. Nullam tincidunt porta nulla, a consectetur sapien venenatis in. Phasellus elementum est sit amet sem accumsan tincidunt. In semper vulputate risus, sed sollicitudin libero
    consectetur eget. Curabitur pulvinar eleifend augue. Sed facilisis ligula sed arcu vulputate tempus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Ut mi nisi, mattis sed est a, luctus aliquet metus. Integer
    fringilla, massa nec laoreet dapibus, odio sem convallis massa, a vestibulum tellus mi in massa. Sed at vulputate velit, id sagittis sem. Vestibulum ac libero massa. Vivamus et libero vel orci auctor sodales a a quam. Vivamus semper tortor eget lacus
    euismod, non dignissim tellus feugiat. Donec tincidunt nisi at ornare ullamcorper. Nulla at mi nulla. Phasellus ligula ante, vehicula sit amet mauris et, consectetur mollis odio. Donec massa risus, ultricies et enim quis, vestibulum consectetur arcu.
    Nunc sed convallis dui, sagittis imperdiet metus. Sed non ultrices velit. Nullam arcu sem, varius non pulvinar id, convallis eget erat. Nam porta tincidunt lorem, non venenatis sapien hendrerit vitae. Suspendisse nec est leo. Nunc commodo, lectus
    nec facilisis laoreet, ex velit dapibus dui, et aliquet lacus est non velit. Vestibulum nisl velit, tempor vel lacus at, ultricies pellentesque nisi. Mauris velit tortor, aliquam a magna eget, efficitur fringilla erat. Praesent massa nisl, maximus
    sit amet viverra in, varius vel urna. Pellentesque eget leo vitae neque dictum egestas at ullamcorper nulla. Aenean lacinia venenatis metus, in faucibus dolor sollicitudin eget. Sed volutpat sit amet urna vel molestie. Donec dignissim velit tortor,
    a blandit ligula commodo dapibus. Vestibulum ac dolor facilisis mauris maximus mattis. Nullam vitae libero ut ligula sodales accumsan et vel dui. Quisque dapibus, lacus accumsan interdum efficitur, tellus augue maximus ipsum, quis ultricies dolor
    justo in diam. Pellentesque id lobortis diam. Suspendisse mollis eget orci eu auctor. Nullam porttitor arcu mi, nec varius magna viverra quis. Fusce eleifend sodales turpis et hendrerit.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer" id="copyright" style="text-align:center">
  <div id="cpy">&copy; DA COSTA JOAO (2019)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @DacJo213 Check again

Comment: I like this code! it will resize automatically depending on window size which is what I was looking for. Only thing is that it shouldn't leave the grey space on the left and right of it. Thanks!!

Comment: @DacJo213 The gray is the background color of the body. If you don't need the gray, remove it from the body selector's rules. If you want a different color, you can add a background-color to `.header` selector

Comment: checked again, still has the grey space on the left and right of the div containing the background ?

Comment: @DacJo213 I didn't change anything, as I don't know, if you want the grey in the first place

Comment: Well I wanted to have the background image take the full size of the div, I don't want to see the grey space, the background image should fill the grey space. Is this possible ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @DacJo213 In your OP you wanted the background-image to take 90% of the width. You can't have both: 90% and 100%

Comment: well I was talking about 100% in width and 90% in height, excuse me for the misunderstanding

Comment: @DacJo213 Then check again